# Force AndEngine Modifiers to Start in JUnit

Tags: java, android, junit, andengine, modifier

I'm trying to test my AndEngine code but can't get a MoveByModifier to start running in my Junit test.

Neither Engine, Scene, nor any Entity subclass seems to give an any methods to explicitly start modifiers, nor do the AndEngine examples ( ) seem to show any way to do this.

I've checked that the Engine is running.  This code passes:

```
engine.start();
assertTrue(engine.isRunning());
```

I'm also sure the modifiers are attached because this passes:

`assertTrue(enemySprite.getEntityModifierCount() == 1);`

It's worth mentioning that the modifier is added to the AnimatedSprite after the AnimatedSprite is added to the Scene.  It's a real time game and I can't be constantly detaching and reattaching sprites every time they change direction, can I?  I'd think it would create a weird flickering effect to constantly remove and add things.

As a side note, I've noticed that AndEngine doesn't seem to integrate particularly well with Junit.

Any thoughts on this, or am I just not using the right approach?  All suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: chek may be hlepfull http://nicolas-gramlich.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-junit-test-runner.html

Comment: one more http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/android/UnitTesting.html

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those articles are very helpful :\  The first is about testing AndEngine itself (as a library, rather than testing an app using it) and is not specific to modifiers.  The second article is about Android unit testing in general.